# Rails 2.3 app is not being published correctly on unicorn server (stylesheets get HTTP 404)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I am trying to deploy an old rails app to an unicorn server on my dev machine.
The problem is that the app is not running correctly because stylesheets are not displayed.

I am starting the server via bundler.

> *bundle exec unicorn*

```
I, [2016-01-11T19:40:09.403219 #23668]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=5
I, [2016-01-11T19:40:09.403357 #23668]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2016-01-11T19:40:09.404184 #23668]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2016-01-11T19:40:09.405295 #23681]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=23681
I, [2016-01-11T19:40:09.405631 #23681]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
worker=0 ready
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2016 19:41:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.1429
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jan/2016 19:41:33] "GET /stylesheets/main.css?1311631772 HTTP/1.1" 404 664 0.1346
```

The server log displays HTTP **404** for *main.css* and the app is being rendered without css styles!

When running on WEBrick server everything works fine, so it has to be a specific problem according to unicorn.

> *bundle exec script/server*

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-01-11 19:30:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-01-11 19:30:50] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2013-12-22) [i686-darwin14.5.0]
[2016-01-11 19:30:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=23474 port=3000
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.8.7'
gem 'rails', '2.3.5'
gem 'warden', '0.10.3'
gem 'devise', '1.0.6'
gem 'delocalize', '~> 0.1.4'
gem 'rdoc'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'unicorn', '4.9.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using that monkey hack:
https://gist.github.com/defunkt/424352

For production I had to uncomment the if statements in line 38 and 71.